# Sum of quotients

Tags: real-analysis, inequality

Assume $0<x_i\leq y<z$ for $i=1\ldots,n$.

Is there an easy argument to show
$$\frac{x_1}{y}+\sum_{i=1}^{n-1} \frac{x_{i+1}}{x_i}+\frac{z}{x_n}\geq n+\frac{z}{y}?$$

---

For $n=1$ the statement is that for $0<x\leq y<z:$

$$\frac{x}{y}+\frac{z}{x} \geq 1+\frac{z}{y}$$

which is equivalent to

$$\frac{z}{y}-\frac{x}{y}\leq \frac{z-x}{x}$$

and this is true. But I see no easy argument for the general case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** $(x_1, x_2,\dots,x_n, z)$ and $(\frac1{x_1}, \frac1{x_2},\dots, \frac1{x_n}, \frac1y)$ are ordered opposite, hence the result follows from Rearrangement inequality.

Comment: Why can we assume that these tuples are ordered? We have $x_i\leq y$ but not $x_i\leq x_{i+1}$.

Comment: @Listing just like $a, b, c$ and $1/a, 1/b, 1/c$ are ordered opposite. I am not saying they are currently ascending or descending.  However if you order them ascending, the corresponding reciprocals will be descending and vice versa. That's all we need to say the RHS of your inequality is lowest among any possible permutation of $x_i$ in the LHS.